# drupal db schema error

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

In a module I'm building for Drupal 7 I'm trying to create a DB schema for the installing and uninstalling process. When enabling the module (and thus installing it) I get an error and my table is not created.

Can anybody see where it's going wrong?

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_schema().
 */
function wind_and_waves_schema() {
  $schema['wind_and_waves'] = array(
   'description' => 'Caches wind and waves data',
   'fields' => array(
     'id' => array(
       'description' => 'The unique identifier for this item.',
       'type' => 'serial',
       'disp-width' => '11',
       'unsigned' => TRUE,
     ),
     'creation' => array(
       'description' => 'Moment the data has been loaded',
       'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'load_time' => array(
       'description' => 'Moment the wind data has been loaded by rijkswaterstaat',
       'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'hoek_wind_snelheid' => array(
       'description' => 'Windsnelheid op hoek',
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'hoek_wind_stoot' => array(
       'description' => 'Windstoot op hoek',
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'hoek_wind_richting' => array(
       'description' => 'Windrichting op hoek',
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'hoek_golf_hoogte' => array(
       'description' => 'golfhoogte op hoek',
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'ijmuiden_wind_snelheid' => array(
       'description' => 'Windsnelheid op ijmuiden',
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'ijmuiden_wind_stoot' => array(
       'description' => 'Windstoot op ijmuiden',
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'ijmuiden_wind_richting' => array(
       'description' => 'Windrichting op ijmuiden',
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'ijmuiden_golf_hoogte' => array(
       'description' => 'golfhoogte op ijmuiden',
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'golf_periode' => array(
       'description' => 'golfperiode',
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'watertemp' => array(
       'description' => 'watertemperatuur',
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
     'luchttemp' => array(
       'description' => 'luchttemperatuur',
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'disp-width' => '11',
     ),
   ),
   'primary key' => array('id'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
?>
```

The error I get:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Windsnelheid op hoek', `hoek_wind_stoot` VARCHAR DEFAULT ' at line 4: CREATE TABLE {wind_and_waves} ( `id` INT unsigned auto_increment DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The unique identifier for this item.', `creation` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Moment the data has been loaded', `hoek_wind_snelheid` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Windsnelheid op hoek', `hoek_wind_stoot` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Windstoot op hoek', `hoek_wind_richting` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Windrichting op hoek', `hoek_golf_hoogte` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'golfhoogte op hoek', `ijmuiden_wind_snelheid` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Windsnelheid op ijmuiden', `ijmuiden_wind_stoot` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Windstoot op ijmuiden', `ijmuiden_wind_richting` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Windrichting op ijmuiden', `ijmuiden_golf_hoogte` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'golfhoogte op ijmuiden', `golf_periode` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'golfperiode', `watertemp` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'watertemperatuur', `luchttemp` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'luchttemperatuur', PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT 'Caches wind and waves data'; Array ( ) in db_create_table() (line 2657 of /home/sitede01/domains/sitedezign.net/public_html/includes/database/database.inc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All columns of type `varchar` need a `length` property, e.g.:

```
'luchttemp' => array(
   'description' => 'luchttemperatuur',
   'type' => 'varchar',
   'length' => 11
 )
```

`disp-width` is only valid for *non-varchar* type columns

Comment: Thanks Clive,

This did remove the error, however it doesn't create the database table at all.

Comment: That sounds about right, the module will be in an inconsistent state now (i.e. it thinks that tables have already been installed). Try disabling your module, then go to the 'Uninstall' tab of the modules page and uninstall it completely. Then go back to the modules page and re-enable it. If that still doesn't work, install the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and visit `mysite.com/devel/reinstall` where you can invoke a full re-installation of the module